# Specifying a "OR" in python package install_requires

Tags: python, pypi

When creating a python package, in distutils.core.setup(), I want to specify, "this package requires install of either package A or package B"

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
   name="",
   install_requires=["pandas"]  # I want ["fastparquet" | "pyarrow"]
)
```

To signify that this package will run if any one of "fastparquet" or "pyarrow" is installed

Comment: Don't get the point really, make a requirements.txt if you are releasing it to the public. And just add the requirements depending on which one you want to use.

Comment: I want to ensure that either fastparquet or pyarrow is installed before this package gets installed. install_requires will install pandas, but is there any way in which user can be prompted to install one of "pyarrow" or "fastparquet" OR just for the sake of using the filter in PyPi